# List of migration sites should be dynamic, based on reputation at destination

Tags: feature-request, migration

The list of migration options when closing as off-topic should be dynamically generated, based upon how much reputation the user has on the destination site. If they have none, then the only option would be to the child meta.

Currently the migration list is a fixed set of Stack sites where the question can be moved. Migration to other sites is possible only by voting to close (or flagging into the review queues).

This is OK and it makes sense.

However, if the user wants to migrate a question to another site already and has some reputation level (e.g. 300) on the target site (e.g. unix.stackexchange.com), this site should an option on the list.

This will guarantee that user has knowledge of the target site's topic and/or scope.

The other current issue is that right now the list is static, even if the question wouldn't belong on any of the options.

**Current situation**

Anyone who reaches vote to close level can vote to move without any knowledge to a set of sites.

[image: Current]

**Proposed - Not enough reputation on any target sites**

As you can see, user still may mark question as off-topic, but can not vote to move.
Also important thing is [link to reputation requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).

[image: Insufficient Reputation]

And - reputation requirements reached on two sites

The per site meta should be always there, but if the question is technically specific, again, can end up in the wrong place.

[image: Enough Reputation]

Comment: An interesting suggestion - provided it solves an actual problem. Does anybody have numbers on how many migrations to targets outside the list are made by the mods?

Comment: @Pekka: The issue is how many migrations to targets outside the list **aren't** made by the mods. Often perfectly good (for a target site) questions get closed without migration, because there's no easy option in the dialog box.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail I thought mods can migrate anywhere? I can be wrong though.

Comment: @Pekka: I mean there's no easy way to tell the mods you think it should be migrated to a particular site.

Comment: Agree - however, the rep required on the target site should be lower, for example 300. If a user already has 3k rep to close a post, they only need 300 rep to know enough about the scope of the target site to make a good judgement.

Comment: @ronalchn Agree, it was just bad proposal, I edited my question.

Comment: @ronalchn I'd say the opposite, the rep requirement should be at least 3000. If you can't vote to close/re-open on the target site, you don't get to suggest that a question belongs there...

Comment: @YannisRizos I'd say "if you can't vote to close/re-open on the target site, you" better pass your suggestion through moderators (as it happens now). Anyone should "have a right" to appeal to mods, including low rep users

Comment: @rkosegi The ultimate answer will be a red tag, and an answer from a Team member. I suggest you keep on improving it (if you deem it necessary of course) until you receive an answer. :)

Comment: @rkosegi By the way, don't get discouraged if you don't get an answer in... weeks or months. There are *tons* of feature requests still currently open and the answer sometimes comes soon, sometimes not. So just wait. :D

Comment: Just a note that Meta should always be an option, since on all sites except Stack Overflow your Meta rep is the same as your main site rep. I don't think there's a need to make an exception for SO

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We now have the new review system….

So why not capture the subjected migration from all users that can vote to close, but then get it confirmed by users with enough rep on the other side.

So:

- You can vote to migrate to a target site provided you have at least
  used the other side.
- At least n people with more than 3000 rep on the target site must
  votes for the migration before it is done.
- Questions that have been voted to be migrated to a given site are
  shown in the review process to users that have more than 3000 rep on
  that site.

Comment: 3000? Maybe it's just my 'newbie'ishness, but isn't that too much?

Comment: @YatharthROCK, it may depend on the target site, on same sites over 3000 rep is very common, on others reps tend to be a low lower

Comment: @YatharthROCK 3k rep is the amount you need to vote to close on graduated sites.  Surely the rep level that grants you the power to judge what's off-topic should match the rep-level that grants you the poewr to judge what's on-topic... right?