# Why does vote to close have static "belongs on" list?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just voted to close what I thought was a perfectly good discussion question on Stack Overflow concerning C coding styles. To me, it seemed to belong on [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

I had to choose "Off Topic", because the options in the "belongs on" list were not appropriate, and I could not override the list with Programmers. Would an appropriate change be to allow looking up another Stack Exchange site?

Also, what other way could I have handled this situation other than commenting to re-post?

Here is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750163/c-coding-style-use-of-if-statements#comment17225768_12750163):
Thanks.

After many comments, here is a third question. Does stackexchange have a discussion forum? Clearly, that is where the question I voted to close belongs.

Comment: Because in most cases, it's not a good post

Comment: These questions come up a lot.  Every once in a while someone will do a query to see the actual number of migrations due to flags; after the first five it generally gets down to single digit questions per month, or close to it anyway.  It's simply something that can be managed easily enough by flagging for mod attention.

Comment: I'd prefer an option to choose an arbitrary site in addition to the static list.

Comment: Yes, but why was I offered a stackexchange database site, rather than programmers?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Because there have been more questions migrated to that site than to programmers.  Almost all of the questions that people think should be moved to programmers don't actually belong on SE in the first place.

Comment: @Dave Newton So the best I can do is vote to close without specifying where it should go and then add a comment? That's what I did, and it was the best I could do.

Comment: @Servy Got it. That list is based on use. I understand.

Comment: I don't see a design/architecture question in there, why do you think it should go on Programmers?

Comment: Yeah, looking at the question it most certainly shouldn't be migrated to programmers.  Codereview... maybe, if it's cleaned up a lot.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus AFAIK yes, because you can't specify a site automatically.

Comment: @YannisRizos` You are probably correct that it was not a discussion about how to code up something. So, if not programmers, then where, or was it too discussion oriented for any stackexchange site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proposal for migration rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147804/proposal-for-migration-rules)

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators

Comment: I regularly run into questions that are solely about statistics and belong on Cross Validated (in some cases I've flagged it for mod review and it was later migrated). What if the list depended on the tags of the question? If a question has the tag "statistics," than by far the most likely other location for it is Cross Validated.

Comment: `"Does stackexchange have a discussion forum?"` Nope.  Just chat.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that this question probably isn't suited for Programmers, the question of "why can't I pick site x to migrate too" or "let me pick from a complete list of sites to migrate" has been asked many times in several different forms.

There are several here:

- [Migrate to *any* site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86928/182513)
- [Migrate shortlist based on tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68022/182513)
- [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96205/182513)
- [How to migrate question to programmers.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91381/182513)

But the short of it is we don't want to give the flagger the option to migrate to any one of the 80+ sites.  First it is too many to sort through to find one, and the more options you present, the more likely it is someone is going to pick the first one that looks close rather than the one that is most appropriate.

Of course, you can always select "Other" as the reason and put the site you think it should go to in your description.  And when flagging as off-topic, you do not have to select a site.  You can just flag off topic and leave it at that.

And as per @YannisRizos' comment in [this recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149280/182513), Programmers used to be on the list, but anything that was decided as a bad SO question, people tried to migrate to Programmers, and you ended up with a bunch of junk on both sites that needed cleaned up.

Add in the interest of full disclosure, I probably have suggested more than my fair share of junk questions to Programmers and other sites.  In the end, I realized you just can't actively try to migrate posts to other sites unless you spend a lot of time there as you might know what the site is about, but you really don't know what is considered crap on the other site.  See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382/182513) about a plea to stop migrating crap (thanks @MarkTrapp for finding it)

Comment: Got it. Good answer, and thanks.

Comment: In re your penultimate paragraph, see also [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)

Comment: @MarkTrapp Which penultimate paragraph? Whose?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus my last paragraph... he was point to a plea he wrote about not migrating junk

Comment: @psubsee2003 Got it. I have no desire to migrate junk. I edited my OP to ask a third question.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus I don't think anyone was suggesting you had any intention.  I just made a point not to do it as a general statement for anyone who was reading this